# Is it possible to run Web Server using Flask microframework simultaneously with a loop?

Tags: python, flask

I try to create a Web Server using Flask and I want to add an infinite loop just like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
   return "This is my website". 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
   while True:
       print("Hello World")
```

but when I run the program, string "Hello World" is never printed, is there a solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: You can use the loops, yes, just not infinite ones

Comment: Can you try putting `app = Flask(__name__)` and  `@app.route("/")` inside the `def main():`?

Comment: @Bazinga, then the Flask server won't start

Comment: Oh, ok. No experience with Flask so gave a naive suggestion

Answer (score 1):

That is to be expected, since `app.run()` is an infinite loop via werkzeug(which is a WSGI utility library that is used by flask). So the simple answer is no, it is not possible under those circumstances. What you'll need to do is use something like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html)

Comment: what is the main difference between multiprocessing and threading ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python) should answer that one.